# translate to a fixed position when AI reach target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, transform, target

I'm trying to have the AI agent stand on a fixed position by the actual target.

I've been asked to share the code. It's one script of the Final State Machine, I've found online.

Here's the entire state code in C#:

```
public class GoToSpecificPoint : IShopperState
{
private readonly StatePatternShopper shopper;
private readonly float distanceFromShelfModifier = 1.5f;

private int nextWayPoint;

private bool enRoute = false;
private bool waitingForPlayer = false;

private float initialPlayerDistanceFromShelf = 1f;
private Transform playerTransform;
private Vector3 targetLocation;

private bool inPlayerSpace = false;
private bool alreadyPicked = false;

public GoToSpecificPoint(StatePatternShopper statePatternShopper)
{
    shopper = statePatternShopper;
}

public void UpdateState()
{
    if (PlayerStillAtShelf())
    {
        enRoute = false;
        waitingForPlayer = true;
    }

    else if (waitingForPlayer && !PlayerStillAtShelf())
    {
        waitingForPlayer = false;
        ToReachPointState();
    }

    }

private bool PlayerStillAtShelf()
{
    float dist;

    if ((dist = Vector3.Distance(targetLocation, playerTransform.position)) > (initialPlayerDistanceFromShelf * distanceFromShelfModifier))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public void SpecificPoint(Vector3 target, Transform player)
{
    alreadyPicked = false;
    enRoute = true;
    playerTransform = player;
    target = new Vector3(player.position.x, 0, player.position.z - 1);
    targetLocation = target;

    initialPlayerDistanceFromShelf = Vector3.Distance(targetLocation, playerTransform.position);

    shopper.meshRendererFlag.material.color = Color.red;
    shopper.navMeshAgent.destination = targetLocation;
    shopper.navMeshAgent.Resume();

    shopper.animator.SetBool("Walk", true);
}
```

}

I want the "target" to be really close to the player, so the AI stands at a fixed transform by the player.

EDIT: The scene is a supermarket and the target is a user. The user is approaching the shelf, and the AI is approaching the user. So I need them to stand in one line.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly - you want to fix your AI to some position when it's really close to it?

Comment: In what way did you current code fail? Is it getting close to the target, but stopping short? Is it not moving at all? Is the target an on-navmesh location?

Comment: @Fiffe I guess you can say that. I want to fix my AI to a position relative to the target. Today most of the scripts has the AI to go to a target, I want it to go stand near the target.

Comment: @Serlite, First, it simply not working even after COBO reply. It is getting close to the target, but stops at different places. My target is a moving user, and once the user enters the collider it triggers the AI to approach him. The user is walking on a navmesh location as well as the AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in your code that you're calculating the **target** position but in the next line instead of assign that **target** to the **targetLocation**. You're making this:

```
target = new Vector3 (player.position.x, 0, player.position.z - 1);
target = targetLocation; // you are overriding the above calculated target
```

Change the line for this:

```
targetLocation = target;
```

Because below you're assigning the **targetLocation**. Here:

```
shopper.navMeshAgent.destination = targetLocation;
```

Comment: hi. can you provide me your full script so that i can study it and test it carefully.